# Adding a row to Radlistbox having ItemTemplate from client side

Tags: asp.net, telerik

How to add a row to radlistbox on clicking add button from client side(Javascript)as my radlistbox also contains Item template

```
<telerik:RadListBox ID="rlbControl" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple"> 
           <ItemTemplate> 
              <table>
               <tr>
                   <td>
                       <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' ></asp:Label>
                   </td>
                   <td style="width:20px"></td>
                   <td >
                       <asp:Label ID="lblAge" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Age") %>' ></asp:Label> 
                   </td>
               </tr>
             </table>
           </ItemTemplate> 
        </telerik:RadListBox>

Name : <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
Age : <asp:TextBox ID="txtAge" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Text="Add" OnClick="btnAdd_Click"  />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this with ItemTemplate as ItemTemplates are server based.

You need to make use of the ClientTemplate. As the name goes, this is the template you provide to work with on the client side.

take a look at this demo.

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/listbox/examples/functionality/clienttemplates/defaultcs.aspx

That should help you out.